# Multi Select Combo Box in Datagrid In Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I want to implement a multi select combox in side a column of datagrid.

I have searched on google but i didn't find proper solution. So could you please help me out to solve this problem.

And also multiselect combo box should be bind with database and select values should be saved in database from datagrid.

Please help me if you have any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Rajbir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the multi select example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42133/Multiple-Selection-ComboBox-for-Silverlight this should give you a good idea. Also following url gives you step by step instruction on how to bind combo box in a data grid http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2011/05/06/Binding-a-Datagride28099s-ComboBox.aspx I hope you know how to get data from server using either ecf/ria services and bind data to the view through view model.